# Mozilla does not recognize display:inline-block inside display:table-cell container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build fluid layout using CSS with following code. (Sorry If I include to much).

Here is code for reset.css

```
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}
fieldset,img { 
    border:0;
}
address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var {
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
}
ol,ul {
    list-style:none;
}
caption,th {
    text-align:left;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-size:100%;
    font-weight:normal;
}
q:before,q:after {
    content:'';
}
abbr,acronym { border:0;
}
```

Here is code for mycss.css

```
.border
{
/*
    border-color:#000000;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
*/  
    background-color: #000000;
}

.border-aqua
{
/*
    border-color: #13eded;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
*/  
    background-color: #12eded;
}

.border-red
{
/*
    border-color: #ff0404;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
*/
    background-color: #ff0404;
}

.border-green
{
/*
    border-color: #008100;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
*/
    background-color: #008100;
}

.border-blue
{
/*
    border-color: #0000fd;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
*/
    background-color: #0000fd;
}

.border-blue:hover
{
    background-color: #ff0404;
}

#title
{
    margin: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    width:auto;

    display: block;

}

#ide
{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    height: 80%;

    width: auto;


    display: block;
}

#container
{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:table;
}

#tasks
{
    height: 100%;
    width:250px;
    display:table-cell;
}


#selectedView
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    display: table-cell;
}

.selectedTasks
{   
    height:30px;
    width: 150px;
    display: block;


    display:-moz-inline-stack;
    display:block;


    background-color: #878787;

}

#selectedViewExpander
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 15px;
    display: table-cell;
}


#area
{
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

and here is html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>
        <link href="./css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
        <link href="./css/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="title" class="border"></div>
        <div id="ide">
            <div id="container" class="border">
                <div id="tasks" class="border-red"></div>
                <div id="selectedView" class="border-green">
                    <p class="selectedTasks">Copy</p>
                    <p class="selectedTasks">Past</p>
                    <p class="selectedTasks">Cut</p>
                </div>
                <div id="selectedViewExpander" class="border-blue"></div>
                <div id="area" class="border-aqua">

                </div>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have problem with displaying this page in Mozilla. However in Chrome and Safari everything work properly. I am new at css and html. If somebody gives me advice on this it will be really appreciated. Or give some idea how I can figure out this kind of problems in future. Thank you in advance.

Link to [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TEy2p/)

Comment: Could you build a test case? jsfiddle.net is a good place to do so.

Comment: I create tast case in fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/TEy2p/. You can open it in two different browsers like chrome and mozilla. And you will see difference. And you can see that "Copy", "Past", "Cut" elements outside of div's borders.

Comment: Your doctype is wrong `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: To Rob. Sorry i correct it. However nothing changed in Mozilla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick `vertical-align:top;` into `#selectedView` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/TEy2p/1/

At the moment, Firefox is placing your text along the bottom of the table cell.

Comment: Thank you. You are my HERO. But can you explain little bit about why it works on webkit engine but not in gecko? Or if it is possible give me some link to read about this. Thank you again.

Comment: I don't know this for sure, but maybe the user agents of other browser have different `vertical-align`-values set (e.g. already to top).

Comment: In both cases for div element with id="selectedView" is set to  "vertical-align:baseline".

Comment: I can only echo what kleinfreund said, the webkit and gecko engines render a lot of things differently, this is just one example of that.

Comment: To gaynorvader. Thank you a lot. When I will have enough reputation I will rate your answer.

Comment: To gaynorvader. Can you recommend me css reseter which will reset rest of css params?

Answer (score 2):

please check out some updates like float property in mycss.css

```
#tasks
    {
        height: 100%;
        width:250px;
        display:table-cell;
        float:left;
    }
    #selectedView
    {
        height: 100%;
        width: 200px;
        display: table-cell;
        float:left;
    }
    #selectedViewExpander
    {
        height: 100%;
        width: 15px;
        display: table-cell;
        float:left;
    }
```

**Update:** 
I have check the first answer and it works perfectly chrome but not in mozila.
try to apply above code and let me know.

Comment: No, it does not work for me. if I add float:left the other divs the form which I am building does not look properly.

Comment: I try the first answer and it works in Mac. But your answer does not work. Even it broke the form.

Comment: ok... but vertical-align:top; working on mozila not a chrome.

Comment: It works in both. Try to open http://jsfiddle.net/TEy2p/1/ in two browser and you will not see difference.